# RakNet AutoRPC vs Packet Implementation

Tags: c++, networking, raknet

I just wanted to ask which of these is more efficient, in both memory and RAM. I know if one is quick than the other I have really no issue using it for everything, I also don't mind using a mixture.

Thanks.